# Haskell Beginner problems, list comprehension with single input

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am brand new to haskell and functional programming in general.

How can I create a function that finds all odd numbers less than 200 that are divisible by 3 and 7 using only list comprehension?

this is my code:

```
oddsDivisible3and7 :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> [Integer] 
oddsDivisible3and7 xs = [x | x <- [1..xs],x mod 3 == 0 && x mod 7 == 0,x < 200]
```

and the errors it is throwing:

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘(Integer -> Integer -> Integer)
                                -> Integer -> Integer’
              with actual type ‘Integer’  
• The function ‘x’ is applied to two arguments,
  but its type ‘Integer’ has none
  In the first argument of ‘(==)’, namely ‘x mod 3’
  In the first argument of ‘(&&)’, namely ‘x mod 3 == 0’
```

with another block for the `mod 7`

I'm not looking for a written function, I just need some guidance.

Comment: If your function accepts a list of integers its signature must be `oddsDivisible3and7 :: [Integer] -> [Integer]`, which means "a function that accepts a list of integers and returns a list of integers"

Comment: If you want "all odd numbers less than 200 that are divisible by 3 and 7", then I don't see how you'd usefully make that a function. That fully specifies the result without any input, so it'd just be a list of numbers.

Comment: the input is supposed to determine the length of the list to be made? or returned i believe as i have a main to work off of and this is how the function is called.
        putStrLn("Input: 200")  
        putStr("Output: ")  
        print(oddsDivisible3and7 200)  
        putStrLn("")

Comment: Im also pretty sure this is supposed to simply be practice for general coding not anything super usefui

Comment: Oh, the number 200 is supposed to be the input? You can't hardcode it in the function if it's supposed to be the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few type error and a few sintax error, let me show:

```
oddsDivisible3and7 :: Integral a => a -> [a]
oddsDivisible3and7 n = [x | x <- [1..n],
 x `mod` 3 == 0 && x `mod` 7 == 0 && x < 200 && x `mod` 2 /= 0]
```

first of all the type should be: `Integral a => a -> [a]`

Then, you want the divisible by 3, 7 and the odds (not divisible by 2), and all less than 200.

example:

```
oddsDivisible3and7 500
=> [21,63,105,147,189]
```